# JSONB Query in Power BI

Tags: sql, powerbi, business-intelligence, postgresql-9.4

I am using postgres as database with table containing **jsonb** attribute. I want to apply filter in power BI on the key or field of that jsonb attribute while fetching data. Is there any way to do so in Power BI, if not is there any other BI tool which supports querying jsonb of postgres or similar types in other databases such as mysql, oracle, etc.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name https://www.compose.com/articles/faster-operations-with-the-jsonb-data-type-in-postgresql/ here it says "Since version 9.4, PostgreSQL offers a significant speedup when using the binary representation of JSON data, jsonb, which can give you that extra edge you need to increase your performance."

Comment: Right, I mixed that with 9.3 - but that doesn't change the fact that you shouldn't be using 9.4 anymore